# XQuery get position of node relative only to siblings with same tag name

Tags: xml, list, position, xquery, basex

I am trying to add an attribute to an tag in XQuery that corresponds to its position, but only concerning siblings of the same tag name. Specifically, items in a list. So here's 2 potential outputs of the query:

```
<list>
    <title>foo</title>
    <item>bar1</item>
    <item>bar2</item>
</list>

 <list>
     <item>bar1</item>
     <item>bar2</item>
</list>
```

And for both, here's the desired outcome when adding the attribute:

```
<list>
    <title>foo</title>
    <item position="1">bar1</item>
    <item position="2">bar2</item>
</list>

 <list>
     <item position="1">bar1</item>
     <item position="2">bar2</item>
</list>
```

The current query I'm using is:

```
count($item/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

But then the count includes every tag, not just `item` ones. So in the example above with the title tag, it counts that, so I get:

```
<list>
    <title>foo</title>
    <item position="2">bar1</item>
    <item position="3">bar2</item>
</list>
```

I've tried a few things, such as subtracting the count of all children of the list that don't have the `item` tag name, such as:

```
    count($item/preceding-sibling::*)+1-count($list/*[local-name() != 'item'])
```

and a bunch of other similar methods but to no avail. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Here's a contextual example of how I'm doing it. Input data:

```
<LIST1>
    <TITLE>REASON FOR REVISION</TITLE>
    <L1ITEM KEY="L1I10254244923043">
        <PARA>Summary - Background: Updated and added related references.</PARA>
    </L1ITEM>
    <L1ITEM KEY="L1I20300231297755">
        <PARA>Summary - Action: Updated to add more work and new groups and configurations.</PARA>
    </L1ITEM>
</LIST1>
```

Then I pass the LIST1 root element into this function:

```
declare function local:listx($listx as element()){
   <list level="{substring(name($listx),5)}">
   {
     for $lxitem in $listx/*
     return if (name($lxitem) = "TITLE") then (
       <title>{local:concatText($lxitem)}</title>
     )
     else local:extract($lxitem, "item", [
       ["position", count($lxitem/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
     ])
   }
   </list>
};
```

The `concatText` function just joins all the text together with a space delimiter, no issues with that. The `extract()` function is as follow:

```
declare function local:extract(
  $root as element(), $tag as xs:string, $props as array(*)
) {
  element {$tag}{

    for $prop at $i in $props
    where array:size($prop) != 0
    return attribute {$props($i)(1)} {$prop($i)(2)},

    for $child in $root/*
    return switch(name($child))
      case "TXTGRPHC" return local:plaintext($child)
      case "PARA" return local:plaintext($child)
      case ...
      default return ()

  }
};
```

As a side note, the way I add attributes here, with the whole 2D array `$props` thing, only ever adds the first attribute, the rest are ignored. Though that's another problem.

Comment: just count preceding sibling `item`; `count($item/preceding-sibling::item)+1`?

Comment: Tried that, they all end up having `position="1"`.

Comment: I don't see why counting `preceding-sibling::item` should not work, you might want to edit your question and show minimal but complete samples.

Comment: Shame you can't use XSLT, where this is the default behaviour of `<xsl:number/>`.

Comment: I actually feed the XML that results from this XQuery into Apache FO, along with an XSL file. So I'll look into using XSLT's `<xsl:number/>` there. Though first would like to try and figure out why my XQ is being weird. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you use BaseX, you could use XQuery Update http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update, for instance

```
copy $items := <root>
<list>
    <title>foo</title>
    <item>bar1</item>
    <item>bar2</item>
</list>

 <list>
     <item>bar1</item>
     <item>bar2</item>
</list>
</root>
modify (
for $item in $items/list/item
return insert node attribute {'id'} {count($item/(., preceding-sibling::item))} into $item
)
return $items
```

Result is

```
<root>
  <list>
    <title>foo</title>
    <item id="1">bar1</item>
    <item id="2">bar2</item>
  </list>
  <list>
    <item id="1">bar1</item>
    <item id="2">bar2</item>
  </list>
</root>
```

Comment: I've added a simple contextual example of the data/functions I'm using. I'll try your method, thanks.